# Multithreading help using ExecutorService in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am trying to search a list of words and find the total count of all the words across multiple files.

My logic is to have separate threads for each file and get the count. Finally I can aggregate the total count got from each of the threads.

Say, I have 50 files each of 1MB. The performance does not improve when I am using multiple threads. My total execution time does not improve with `FILE_THREAD_COUNT`. I am getting almost the same execution time when my thread count is either 1 or 50.

Am I doing something wrong in using the executor service?

Here is my code.

```
public void searchText(List<File> filesInPath, Set<String> searchWords) {
    try {
        BlockingQueue<File> filesBlockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(filesInPath.size());
        filesBlockingQueue.addAll(filesInPath);

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(FILE_THREAD_COUNT);
        int totalWordCount = 0;
        while (!filesBlockingQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Callable<Integer> task = () -> {
                int wordCount = 0;
                try {
                    File file = filesBlockingQueue.take();
                    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                        String currentLine;
                        while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            String[] words = currentLine.split("\\s+");
                            for (String word : words) {
                                for (String searchWord : searchWords) {
                                    if (word.contains(searchWord)) {
                                        wordCount++;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Handle error
                }
                return wordCount;
            };
            totalWordCount += executorService.submit(task).get();
        }
        System.out.println("Final word count=" + totalWordCount);
        executorService.shutdown();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're doing something wrong.

The problem is here:

```
executorService.submit(task).get()
```

Your code submits a task then waits for it to finish, which achieves nothing in parallel; the tasks run sequentially. And your `BlockingQueue` adds no value whatsoever.

The way to run tasks in parallel is to *first* submit *all* tasks, collect the `Future`s returned, *then* call `get()` on all of them. Like this:

```
List<Future<Integer>> futures = filesInPath.stream()
    .map(<create your Callable>)
    .map(executorService::submit)
    .collect(toList());

for (Future future : futures)
    totalWordCount += future.get();
}
```

You can actually do it in one stream, by going through the intermediate list (as above) but then immediately streaming that, but you have to wrap the call to `Future#get` in some code to catch the checked exception - I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: How should I create a callable to use it in my streams. This gives me an error
`                Callable<Integer> callable = new SearchFile(filesBlockingQueue);
                List<Future<Integer>> futures = filesInPath.stream()
                        .map(callable)
                        .map(executorService::submit)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());`